# subneting a small store

Tags: wireless-router, switch, subnet

I have a friend with this small store/cyber and want to divide the network like this

```
clients can only see other clients
registers can see other registers
admins can see everyone
```

I currently have a switch linksys SE3020 and a home router D-Link 615 wich can't be changed, I know I could do some subnettig like this

```
192.168.1.0-1 /28
192.168.1.0-31 /27
192.168.0.0-255 /24
```

the problem is I won't get any response form the smaller subnetwork on the /24, I was wondering if there is something I could do that I'm missing, with some software.

Comment: Why do client admins need to see everyone?  Don't have that D-Link router in front of me, but maybe you can DD-WRT it and do some Vlans to at least separate the client and register traffic.  When you say "Registers" I assume you're referring to a POS (Point of Sale) machine?

Comment: DD-WRT sounds like an option, I would have to look into it. I made a mistake there, not client admins, just admins and yes, with registers I mean POS

Comment: If you want admins to be able to talk to both other subnets, they'll need one IP per subnet, for a total of 3 IPs.

Comment: What do you mean by 'see'? ping or something else?

Comment: by 'see' I mean that I'm able to use resources of that computer, get files for example @Putnik

Answer (score 0):

> by 'see' I mean that I'm able to use resources of that computer, get files for example

Then it is work for firewall, not for routing engine (software, not to be confused with the router as equipment). So you have to check firewall on your router (device) - and if it isn't capable to do the job either replace software (like mentioned DD-WRT) or the device completely.